# org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openQuestion How to interact?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an eclipse plugin. One of the files has this code

```
org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openQuestion(null, some function , "Do you agree?");
```

This part of the code pops up a dialog box with a message and has two options, yes or no.

I want to display a new dialog box for yes and nothing else for no.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value returned from calling `openQuestion`:

```
boolean result = MessageDialog.openQuestion(...);
```

and then decide what to do based on that value.